# Adding multiple fields in Java streams (and conditional stream operations)

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Thing {
    private BigDecimal field1;
    private BigDecimal field2;

    private BigDecimal otherField1;
    private BigDecimal otherField2;
    private BigDecimal otherField3;
}
```

and in another class I for-each over a `List<Thing> things`, adding field1 and field2 to a sum that I return when the iteration is done.

But what I want is to accomplish that with Java streams. The following is what I have--it works, but I feel like there has to be a way to condense it down to one stream:

```
public BigDecimal addFields(List<Thing> things) {
    BigDecimal field1sum = things.parallelStream()
                                     .filter(thing -> thing.getField1() != null)
                                     .map(Thing::getField1)
                                     .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

     BigDecimal field2sum = things.parallelStream()
                                     .filter(thing -> thing.getField2() != null)
                                     .map(Thing::getField2)
                                     .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
     return field1sum.add(field2sum);
}
```

I suspect the answer is the `reduce()` method that takes three arguments, one of which is a BiFunction, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make that work. Edit: I think I could pass in `(x,y) -> x.add(y)` to `reduce()`, but then the question becomes how do I `map()` both of those fields?

Additionally, is it possible/how would I go about turning this imperative code into a functional stream?

```
public BigDecimal addOtherFields(List<Thing> things) {
    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (Thing thing : things) {
        if (thing.getOtherField2() != null) {
            BigDecimal otherField2 = thing.getOtherField2();
            otherField2 = thing.getOtherField1().subtract(otherField2);
            result = result.add(otherField2);
         } else if (thing.getOtherField3() != null) {
            BigDecimal otherField3 = thing.getOtherField3();
            otherField3 = thing.getOtherField1.subtract(otherField3);
            result = result.add(otherField3);
         }
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Or, to be a bit more precise, how would I handle that conditional check in a stream based approach? I was trying to `filter()` things out without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're going to treat the fields uniformly, you may consider `flatMap`:

```
public BigDecimal addFields(List<Thing> things) {
    return things.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(thing -> Stream.of(thing.getField1(), thing.getField2()))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
public BigDecimal addOtherFields(List<Thing> things) {
    return things.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(thing ->
            Stream.of(thing.getOtherField2(), thing.getOtherField3())
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(thing.getOtherField1()::subtract)
        ).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `collect()`, with a custom collector helper, not unlike `IntSummaryStatistics`.

```
things.stream()
      .collect(ThingCollectorHelper::new, 
               ThingCollectorHelper::accept,
               ThingCollectorHelper::combine);
```

Your helper class will be something like:

```
class ThingCollectorHelper {
    BigDecimal sum1 = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal sum2 = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    void accept(Thing t) {
        if (t.field1 != null)
            sum1 = sum1.plus(t.field1);
        if (t.field2 != null)
            sum2 = sum2.plus(t.field2);
    }

    void combine(ThingCollectorHelper other) {
        sum1 = sum1.plus(other.sum1);
        sum2 = sum2.plus(other.sum2);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your first method, you want to sum all `field1` and `field2` together, ignoring `null`. You can do this with a single Stream pipeline by, as you hinted, the 3 argument [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method.

In this case, the identity is still `BigDecimal.ZERO`. The accumulator function adds to the current accumulated result each field if they're not null. Finally, the combiner, which is only used for parallel processing, adds the two `BigDecimal` values.

```
public BigDecimal addFields(List<Thing> things) {
    return things.parallelStream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, t) -> {
         if (t.getField1() != null) a = a.add(t.getField1());
         if (t.getField2() != null) a = a.add(t.getField2());
         return a;
     }, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

The same goes for your second example where, in this case, you want to sum the difference between `otherField1` and `otherField2` or `otherField3` depending on whether or not they are `null`:

```
public BigDecimal addOtherFields(List<Thing> things) {
    return things.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, t) -> {
        if (t.getOtherField2() != null) {
            return a.add(t.getOtherField1().subtract(t.getOtherField2()));
        } else if (t.getOtherField3() != null) {
            return a.add(t.getOtherField1().subtract(t.getOtherField3()));
        }
        return a;
    }, BigDecimal::add);
 }
```

Another equivalent way of solving this task would be to use `map()`: in that case, you would map each element into the value you want to sum, and reduce the Stream by summing all `BigInteger`s. For example, in the first example, you would map each `Thing` into the sum of `field1` and `field2`, taking into account their potential `null`-ness.